How to use a Fast Fourier Transform to speed up applying a nested loop over dataframes?
I have two dataframes and a corresponding nested loop. What I want to calculate looks like this in pseudocode:
foreach row1 in df1:
   SUM_row2_in_df2( my_function(row1, row2))

where
my_function(row1, row2) = PROD_over_col(exp(log(0.5) * (row2_col-row1_col)^2 )) 

This results in n values (one for each row in dataframe 1). Due to the double loop it has a runtime of O(n^2). I was told I could reduce this to a runtime of O(n log n) using a Fast Fourier Transform. However, I am unsure how to do that as the examples I find do not include (different) dataframes.
Here is some example code on what I am doing:
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2), c=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2), b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2), c=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0))

n <- nrow(df1)
p <- ncol(df1)

rbf.normal <- function(point, x) {
  exp(log(0.5) * (x-point)^2 )  
}

result <-c()

for (i in 1:n){
  row1 <- df1[i,]
  # sum over all results for df2
  result_i <- 0
  for (j in 1:n){
    row2 <- df2[j,]
    # calculate the kernel function for each column and multiply the results
    result_j <- 1
    for (d in 1:p){
      result_kernel <- rbf.normal(row1[[d]], row2[[d]])
      result_j <- result_j*result_kernel
    }
    result_i <- result_i + result_j
  }
  result <- c(result, result_i)
}

result



Hi, it's impossible to tell unless you provide the code for my_function . Please clarify.   The fact that you use 2 dataframes as input is irrelevant, since you could easily merge them somehow into a single array.

The function I am using is in the code below, but I will edit the question, so that it is obvious from just reading the pseudocode

Can you maybe point to some of the examples you found that used only one data.frame?

If the dataframes were one-dimensional, it would just be the functions of all possible combinations of rows and then summed over df2 to get one value per row in df1. With more dimensions the function just changes to the product of the function applied to each column. Does this help?

I did not find any examples using dataframes, I just wanted to emphasize that in my example the dataframes are different, as most examples I saw used only one vector.

I'm not sure about the FFT, but the computation can be made much faster using a distance matrix:
library(Rfast)

(result2 <- rowsums(exp(log(0.5)*dista(as.matrix(df1), as.matrix(df2))^2)))
#> [1] 3.546875 3.625000 2.078125 3.546875 3.625000 2.078125 3.546875 3.625000
all.equal(result, result2)
#> [1] TRUE


This also works rowsums(exp(log(0.5)*dista(df1, df2, square = TRUE))) and
at least for the question's data this is marginally faster although the added
complexity may not be worth it:
m1 <- as.matrix(df1); m2 <- as.matrix(df2); n <- nrow(m1);  rowsums(exp(log(0.5) * (-2*tcrossprod(m1, m2) +  matrix(rowsums(m2^2), n, n, byrow = TRUE) + rowsums(m1^2))))

Ah, thanks. I didn't notice the square argument, although overall performance suffers slightly when using it. For the tcrossprod approach, it should be matrix(rowsums(m2^2), nrow(m1), nrow(m2), byrow = TRUE) in case the two data.frames have a different number of rows. collapse::setop will be even faster and more memory efficient: rowsums(exp(log(0.5)*setop(rowsums(m1^2) - 2*tcrossprod(m1, m2), "+", rowsums(m2^2), rowwise = TRUE))).
